# After updating to Flutter 1.22 neither VSCode nor Android Studio are able to find file reference

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

After upgrade to flutter 1.22 neither VSCode nor Android Studio is able to resolve the file references. [image: Screenshot from the error]

My setup looks as follows: Two packages the flutter package (client) with all the flutter stuff and the plugins in it and the core package with all the business logic in pure dart.

Since I updated to Flutter 1.22 and uninstalled the dart-sdk. I get the errors as shown in the screenshot.

I already did the following steps:

- Reinstalled the dart-sdk
- `rm -Rf ~/.pub-cache`
- `flutter clean && flutter pub get &&  flutter pub upgrade && flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` - in each folder
- uninstalled / installed the *flutter/dart-plugin*
- added the flutter sdk expliced to `dart.sdkPath`and `dart.flutterSdkPath`

The funny thing is when I open each package alone in VSCode or Android-Studio everything works as expected.

And now I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: did you also try `flutter pub cache repair` ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes